# Can Ethernet Packets be Accessed via WiFi?: Question edited to be on topic

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Can Ethernet Packets be Accessed via WiFi?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43965/can-ethernet-packets-be-accessed-via-wifi)

Hi everybody,

I had a think about the most common occurrence in my experience and edited the question accordingly. Could the hold be removed please?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1):

I didn't vote to close, but didn't vote to reopen either.

This is because I feel it really hard to answer you question.

Even in a very simple, basic, network, the behavior can drastically change depending on:

- the hardware used (brand / models / software versions)
- the configuration made on those devices
- the hosts operating systems, both clients and servers (Windows, MacOs, Linux...)
- the application used

depending on all this, the answer can be "Yes" or "No", or really too long to fit on this site.

This site is more about answering questions on actual issues encountered on a real production network than hypothetical design.

From the Help Center page [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Your question clearly fall under the "don't ask" categories.

So I vote to keep it close, in its current form.

Comment: My question most certainly falls into the "can you please explain packet routing to me" category, and gave a specific example relating to a case I often deal with. How is that bad?

Comment: @JamesGeddes, "_My question most certainly falls into the "can you please explain packet routing to me" category..._" That is a very large subject, covered in entire books: "_If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._" You can edit your question to be more specific, and it will come up for a reopen vote, but it is far too broad, and the specific case of home networking and/or consumer-grade equipment would be off-topic here, as would questions about applications, hosts, servers, and their OSes, etc., but you could ask something about those on [su].